# LaTeX motto/slogan

Tags: latex-misc

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this, I mean, it's not specifically related to LaTeX typesetting. But here it goes.

I'm making a presentation to introduce LaTeX to university students, and I'm looking for a "catchy", or motivating slogan/motto, to use as a title for the presentation. I tried to google it, but I had no success.

I thought something like *"LaTeX: program your documents"*, but I think *"program"* may be misunderstood with *"schedule"*.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: `LaTeX - A road to procrastination` !!!

Comment: `LaTeX - Because MS Word sucks` or `LaTeX - For all the people who hate orphans and widows` or `LaTeX - \expand your mind` or... :)

Comment: @Philipp You are totally right. I hate when I have to use the ugly Word sometimes.

Comment: While I upvoted Harish's comment, I offer one in opposition to his sentiment: "When your document can't be late, it must be LaTeX"

Comment: `Those who can, LaTeX; those who can't, Word.`

Comment: "If you're an underdog, mentally disabled, physically disabled, if you don't fit in, if you're not as pretty as the others, you can still be a hero, read TEXBook!"

Comment: `LaTeX: What you see is what you mean`

Answer (score 12):

### A professional approach:

Leslie Lamport, developer of LaTeX, called it:

> LaTeX – A document preparation system

as is visible on the [LaTeX project website](http://www.latex-project.org/). Moreover, your first slide could include the fundamental use of LaTeX (also from the above reference):

> LaTeX is a high-quality typesetting system; it includes features designed for the production of technical and scientific documentation. LaTeX is the *de facto* standard for the communication and publication of scientific documents. LaTeX is available as free software.

---

### A different approach:

[The TeX Book](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbook) mentions this about TeX:

> It is important to understand the idea of token lists, if you want
> to gain a thorough understanding of TeX, and it is convenient to learn
> the concept by thinking of TeX as if it were a living organism. The
> individual lines of input in your files are seen only by TeX's "eyes"
> and "mouth"; but after that text has been gobbled up, it is sent to
> TeX's "stomach" in the form of a token list, and the digestive processes
> that do the actual typesetting are based entirely on tokens. As far as the
> stomach is concerned, the input flows in as a stream of tokens, somewhat
> as if your TeX manuscript had been typed all on one extremely long line.

How about:

> LaTeX - Your document cookie monster

Comment: "A document preparation system."  Hits the nail on the head.

Answer (score 6):

How about:

> LaTeX : The Art of Professional Typesetting

or

> LateX: A Complete Tool for Producing Professional Essays

Comment: I liked the first one: "the art of professional typesetting" :) it's catchy enough for me

Answer (score 4):

This one expresses best what I think about LaTeX.

> LaTeX – The blueprint for a document

Answer (score 1):

Word: What you see is what you get.
LaTex: What you get is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

"If layout and beauty still will impress,
for drawings and equations, trust LaTeX finesse..."

D.V.